# Heroku app crashes after pushing change with new dependencies

Tags: django, heroku

So I have a Django web app running on Heroku. I recently pushed an update where I added some API functionality via the Django Rest Framework. I installed this via pip. Now my Heroku app crashes. I assume I somehow need to install this dependency on Heroku? Here is the error message:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

I tried entering the Heroku CLI and typing pip install djangorestframework but and running Heroku restart but it still crashes.

Edit: some more details, I tried installing this dependency on my machine via git clone in addition to pip. When I pushed this code to Heroku, in the command line I see cannot stat '/tmp/build_5917e4123a7c/requirements.txt': No such file or directory

Edit2: Just to keep this post updated, I'm not trying to add a requirements.txt file to my project with this dependency in it. The file is in the root directory and the only text in it is:

```
djangorestframework==3.11.0
```

Edit3: I fixed it. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I installed my dependency with pip install djangorestframework but I needed to use pipenv install djangorestframework. The Pipfile therefore never had this dependency added so Heroku wasn't able to see it since it seems Heroku checks the Pipfile. I guess requirements.txt is the old deprecated way to do this?